# How to get bean from spring IOC container which is running on another JVM?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-bean, spring-ioc

I have multi-module application consider Module-A and Module-B that runs two IOC containers IOC-A and IOC-B respectively. I am quite beginner to multi-module architecture. As per my assumption, both modules runs on different JVMs. I am using Spring boot to run both modules. Now I want a bean from IOC-A need to be injected in a bean in IOC-B.
Please suggest how to accomplish it. Thanks

Comment: You can't inject a bean from another JVM. In order to inject a bean from Module A into Module B, both Module A and Module B should run in the same JVM (and Module B would need a dependency on Module A).

Comment: You could use Spring remoting over HTTP: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-remoting-http-invoker